# converting integer to decimal values while adding both

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a vb.net application.

My code is the following:

```
txtTotalPrevious.Text = Val(txtTotalPrevious.Text) + Val(txtoldtotal.text)
```

my values are:

```
txtTotalPrevious.Text=187.0000
txtoldtotal=3
```

I get the result

```
result =190
```

but my expected result is:

```
result=190.0000
```

What is the issue in my logic?

Comment: First of all, don't use Val; it is an old function (old VB6, before .NET) which is well-known for not being too reliable. Secondly, you have to understand the difference between a number (187) and its string representation (187.0000 or 187 and so on). You can convert numbers to strings in various ways. For example, givenNumberVariable.ToString(format), where format is a pattern indicating how the number should be displayed (e.g., zeroes after the decimal separator). The associated MSDN article (or doing some tests by your own) should be more than enough to know how to get what you want.

Comment: Turn on `Option Strict` and you'll see `txtTotalPrevious.Text=187.0000` is an invalid assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `String.Format` if you want to output string be like you want:

```
Dim str1 As String = "187.0000"
Dim str2 As String = "3"
Dim resultString As String = String.Format("{0:0.0000}", Val(str1) + Val(str2))
' And the result will be 190.0000
```

And if you want the double result:

```
Dim resultDouble as Double= Val(str1) + Val(str2)
' And the result will be Double 190
```

**EDIT**

---

Based on varocarbas comments you should consider some notes:

**Avoid using Val method**

> The [Val](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7beh1x9(v=vs.90).aspx) function stops reading the string at the first character it
>   cannot recognize as part of a number. Symbols and characters that are
>   often considered parts of numeric values, such as dollar signs and
>   commas, are not recognized. However, the function recognizes the radix
>   prefixes &O (for octal) and &H (for hexadecimal). Blanks, tabs, and
>   linefeed characters are stripped from the argument.
>   The following call
>   returns the value 1615198.
>   `Val(" 1615 198th Street N.E.")`
>
> The Val function recognizes only the period (.) as a valid decimal
>   separator. When different decimal separators are used, as in
>   international applications, use CDbl or CInt instead to convert a
>   string to a number. To convert the string representation of a number
>   in a particular culture to a numeric value, use the numeric type's
>   Parse(String, IFormatProvider) method. For example, use Double.Parse
>   when converting a string to a Double.

**As a VB.Net Programmer use & instead of + for string concatenation**

> When you use the [+](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9c5t70w2.aspx) operator, you might not be able to determine
>   whether addition or string concatenation will occur. Use the &
>   operator for concatenation to eliminate ambiguity and to provide
>   self-documenting code.

Comment: Please, read my comment above. Relying on Val is not recommendable. There are many much more reliable alternatives (Convert.To, Parse, TryParse, etc.). You can even use VB6 functions (accepted in VB.NET) which are much more reliable than Val.

Comment: @varocarbas Thank you for your comment, you are completely right :) I only focused on String.Format and didn't want to change other parts of code

Comment: But then why are you including Val in your code? You can focus on just the conversion of a number to string. For example: Dim resultString As String = String.Format("{0:0.0000}", numberOne & numberTwo) (by assuming that numberOne and numberTwo are numbers which the OP should have converted from strings). But why adding a code which you know that is not right?! Also if you are aware about something (even despite of not being directly asked), you should comment about it. In any case, please don't write not-too-right parts because will be confusing for future readers (and the OP).

Comment: BTW, you should better use & to concatenate strings rather than + to make sure that there will not be any problem under any circumstance.

Comment: @varocarbas Thank you for your comments, I edited the post. - As a personal preference, I prefer setting Option Strict and use +, but based on formal recommendations I edited the post. Hope you find it useful :)

Comment: Sure. Although this is not for me, but for the future readers and the OP.